# Not able to catch the index of the text where right click is made and contextmenu is triggerred in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

**Context:**
In the below code snippet I am trying to get the index of the text inside the input element where the right click is made on the text. But am able to get only the id of the element on which the right click is made.
Instead I want for text "Hello World" if I right click on the letter 'W' it should return me the index of 'W' i.e. 6.

Below is the code snippet. Any help would be great!

**Code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>index demo</title>
<style>
div {
font-weight: bold;
color: #090;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<body>
<input type="text" id="bar" value="hello world">
<div></div>
<script>
var listItem = $( "#bar" );
console.info('listItem='+listItem.val());
listItem.on("contextmenu",function(event){
    console.info('event=',event);
  console.info($(this).attr('id'));
});
//$( "div" ).html( "Index: " + $( "li" ).index( listItem ) );
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: `.attr('value')`. Getting specific characters from the string is more difficult. If that is needed, dont use a str but individual characters in spans so you can actually discern between the clicked letters.

Comment: @Shilly .val() should work fine, but he still needs to work out what character was clicked on. EG. the 'W' in your example.